# How using stdint.h has advantage of portability?

Tags: c, stdint

I read that `stdint.h` is used for portability, but I'm confused.

If I wrote a program on a 32-bit system, uint32_t (unsigned int) is 4-bytes.

But when this program is run on 16-bit system, int is 2bytes and uint32_t (unsigned int) is 2bytes.

I think portability is not guaranteed in this case.
Is there anything I am understanding wrong?

Comment: `uint32_t` is always 32 bits. That's why it has 32 in the name.

Comment: What 16 bit system? How have you determined that uint32_t is 2 bytes? Please [edit] your question to include these details

Comment: Why would `uin32_t` be `unsigned int` if `int` is only 16 bits? Sounds rather broken. Where did you get that idea?

Comment: porpomas, "... and uint32_t (unsigned int) is 2bytes." ---> No.  Post the code you used to determine that.

Answer (score 6):

> Is there any thing I am understanding wrong?

Yes.

Type `uint32_t` is *always* an unsigned integer type with exactly 32 bits, none of them padding bits.  On many modern systems that corresponds to type `unsigned int`, but on others it might correspond to a different type, such as `unsigned long int`.  On systems that do not have a type with the correct properties, it is not defined at all.

The point of `uint32_t` and the other explicit-width data types from `stdint.h` is exactly to address the issue you raise, that (for example) `unsigned int` has a different size on different machines.

Comment: I thought stdint.h just use typedef. But it seems use other mechanisms like cheking wordsize and include other header files. these thing make the bit size consistent, right?

Comment: @porpomas, the language spec does not specify what mechanism a C implementation uses to define `uint32_t`, *etc*.  A `typedef` is a likely possibility, but not the only one.  But perhaps you are failing to recognize that different C implementations might provide different typedefs for `uint32_t` and other types.

Comment: @porpomas yes, it mostly provides typedef. That does not mean you get the same definitions for every compiler.

Comment: @porpomas: At the end of the day `stdint.h` indeed comes down to `typedef`s, however the particular exact definition of that will be determined at compile time by a combination of preprocessor `#if`s and target macros defined by the compiler itself. Also some compilers (for example GCC and Clang) will define macros with the appropriate type definitions. If using GCC or Clang look at it's output when calling it like this: `gcc -E -dM - < /dev/null | egrep '__.INT.*_TYPE'`

Comment: @porpomas: Now if you were to call it with a different compilation target, those type definition macros would be sufficiently changed for that particular target.

Answer (score 1):

A `uint32_t` and a `uint16_t` are distinct types from `int`.

While the size of `int` may vary, a `uint32_t` is always 32 bit and a `uint16_t` is always 16 bit.